# Solve $ 1 + \frac{\sqrt{x+3}}{1+\sqrt{1-x}} = x + \frac{\sqrt{2x+2}}{1+\sqrt{2-2x}} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> **Solve for** $x \in \mathbb{R}$
>
> $$ 1 + \dfrac{\sqrt{x+3}}{1+\sqrt{1-x}} = x + \dfrac{\sqrt{2x+2}}{1+\sqrt{2-2x}} $$

I tried some substitutions and squaring but that didn't help. I also tried to use inequalities as done in my [previous problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770604/solving-a-radical-equation-for-real-x), but that too didn't help.

Comment: I don't really see why this would have an algebraic solution.  You are going to end up mixing square roots with $x\sqrt{x}$.  $x$ and $\sqrt{x}$ is fine since that should be transformable to a quadratic but _not_ if you have $\sqrt{x}$ and $x\sqrt{x}$.  It seems this would be akin to (possibly) a cubic (but not even sure about that).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Given :** $ 1 + \dfrac{\sqrt{x+3}}{1+\sqrt{1-x}} = x + \dfrac{\sqrt{2x+2}}  {1+\sqrt{2-2x}} $

Let $\alpha = x+3 $ ; $\beta = 2x+2$ ; $\left(\beta - \alpha\right) = x-1$

$\implies 1+ \dfrac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{1+\sqrt{4-\alpha}} = x + \dfrac{\sqrt{\beta}}  {1+\sqrt{4-\beta}} $

$\implies \alpha + \dfrac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{1+\sqrt{4-\alpha}} = \beta + \dfrac{\sqrt{\beta}}  {1+\sqrt{4-\beta}} $

Let $f(x) = x + \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{4-x}}$, the given equation becomes,

$f(\alpha) = f(\beta)$

Note that $f(x)$ is monotonic increasing in its domain,

$\therefore \alpha = \beta$

$\implies x+3 = 2x +2$

$\implies x=\boxed{1}$

Comment: Hello Sir. Can you also help me with [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770880/solve-the-equation-for-x-in-mathbbr) ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that my solution is simpler:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&1+\frac{\sqrt{x+3}}{1+\sqrt{1-x}}=x+\frac{\sqrt{2x+2}}{1+\sqrt{2-2x}}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow& x-1+\frac{\sqrt{2x+2}}{1+\sqrt{2-2x}}-\frac{\sqrt{x+3}}
{1+\sqrt{1-x}}=0\\
&\Longleftrightarrow& x-1+\frac{\sqrt{2x+2}+\sqrt{2x+2}\sqrt{1-x}-\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt{x+3}\sqrt{2-2x}}{(1+\sqrt{2-2x})(1+\sqrt{1-x})}=0\\
&\Longleftrightarrow& x-1+\frac{\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{2x+2}+\sqrt{x+3}}+\frac{4(x-1)}{\sqrt{2x+2}\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{x+3}\sqrt{2-2x}}}{(1+\sqrt{2-2x})(1+\sqrt{1-x})}=0\\
&\Longleftrightarrow& (x-1)\left(1+\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x+2}+\sqrt{x+3}}+\frac{4}{\sqrt{2x+2}\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{x+3}\sqrt{2-2x}}}{(1+\sqrt{2-2x})(1+\sqrt{1-x})}\right)=0\\
&\Longleftrightarrow& x=1.
\end{eqnarray}